# Can a CloudWatch Custom Metric be a variable instead of a hard-coded string

Tags: string, amazon-web-services, namespaces, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

I have created a AWS custom metric in CloudWatch. I am using NodeJs Lambda function to create a custom metric along with dimensions. I would like to know if we can pass variable value to dimensions instead of string (hardcoded strings). Does dimension values accept anything other then string value?

**This works:**

```
var params = {
    MetricData: [
      {
        MetricName: 'PAGES_VISITED',
        Dimensions: [
          {
            Name: 'UNIQUE_PAGES',
            Value: '**URLS**'
          },
        ],
        Unit: 'None',
        Value: 1.0
      },
    ],
    Namespace: 'SITE/TRAFFIC'
  }
```

**But I want to pass something like this:**

```
MetricData: [
    {
      MetricName: 'PAGES_VISITED',
      Dimensions: [
        {
          Name: 'MessageAttributes',
          Value: msgattr
        },
        {
          Name: 'CompanyName',
          Value: process.env.CompanyName
        },
        {
          Name: 'short_description',
          Value: message
        },
      ],
      Unit: 'None',
      Value: 10.0
    },
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work fine.

The `Value` variables for Dimensions can only be strings, but you can provide those strings by referencing variables.

To see the result, simply `print(params)` and you will see that the values from the variables have been stored.

Comment: I can see the printed value, but when I pass the variable to Dimension value i see following error:
Error InvalidParameterType: Expected params.MetricData[0].Dimensions[0].Value to be a string

Comment: What is it showing for the `MessageAttributes` value? Is it showing it as a string?